# Git Автосдвиг строк

Tags: git, phpstorm

В процессе разработки я вношу некие изменения в файл, но гит делает сдвиг строк. Более детально на картинке. В блоке который выделен зелёным, то что вносилось мною, в блоке который выделен красным то что сделал git сам. 
Как избежать какого поведения. Все изменения вносится через PHPStorm.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: а ещё это может быть табуляция-пробелы.

Comment: Добавил параметр git config --global core.autocrlf true который указан в ссылки пользователем user1034749. Похоже помогло.